# Why do I keep getting this message on top of my git terminal?

Tags: git, audacity

[image]

I'm learning about git through Udacity, and when following the instructions this message popped up over my username and I've been struggling to make it leave for the last 30 minutes or so..(I tried resting and the such)

Here's the code:

```
git config --global core.editor "'C:/Program Files/Sublime Text 2/sublime_text.exe' -n -w"
git config --global push.default upstream
git config --global merge.conflictstyle diff3
```

Comment: Can you share your `.bashrc` file? The error probably originates there somewhere.

Comment: https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash  download and install this file to the C://Users/Jamil/ directory

Comment: @AntonSizikov please put these as official answers.

Comment: @JordanParmer okay. Seems a bit too much for an answer tho :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message says that you're missing the `git-complition.bash` file.

You could download it from here https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash

and install it to the location specified in the error message (`C://Users/Jamil/` in your case)